# What do you call the center of a fruit that you eat?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering if there is a word or phrase for the central part of the fruit that you eat. You don't eat the core of the apple. And you eat the centers of bananas and oranges but not the peel. I tried Googling and searching on this site but to no avail.

Comment: Many folks will refer to the edible part of a fruit as "the meat" of it, though that term applies equally to a banana and a peach.

Comment: @thomj1332 I do too, there really isn't a reason not to. Though from pictures I've seen of the size of some apples in the US I can imagine that a whole apple there is a bit much for one sitting.

Comment: @Spagirl - I just have trouble with the hard drives.

Comment: @HotLicks badum-TISH!

Comment: [_This Wikipedia article_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_anatomy) may prove helpful. However, note that different scientific parts are eaten depending on the fruit and its structure. In an apple, the fleshy part is the mesocarp. In an orange, the juicy parts of the segments are actually the endocarp. Contrast this to a drupe, where the endocarp is a hard stone that is definitely not eaten. In a grape, the entirety of the pericarp (all three layers) as well as the seed is eaten. Personally, I would use something generic and non-scientific, such as "flesh."

Comment: @vpn Nice article reference. Although arguably overly scientific for day-to-day conversations, I like the terminology because it not only gives me terms like "endocarp" for fruit such as oranges and bananas, but it also gives terms such as "mesocarp" for fruits where the you eat the middle layer such apples and peaches. If you add your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anatomically, many fruits consist of two primary layers: the *pericarp* and the *seed*. The pericarp is tissue that derives directly from ovary of a flower. It consists of three sub-layers:

- **Epicarp:** the outermost layer of a fruit; forms a tougher "skin" around the fruit
- **Mesocarp:** the middle layer of a fruit, found between the epicarp and the endocarp; usually (but not always) the fleshy part that is consumed
- **Endocarp:** the inner layer of a fruit that directly surrounds the seeds

Additionally, [*accessory fruits*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessory_fruit) have fleshy tissue not derived from the ovary but from other parts of a flower.

Source: [Wikipedia, "Fruit Anatomy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_anatomy)

Depending on the type of fruit, different layers may be physically "fleshy" and eaten. Here are some general guidelines:

- In [**pomes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pome), such as apples, the majority of the flesh is not part of the pericarp (it is not derived from the ovary) but rather is "accessory tissue." The entire pericarp forms the core. (So, the epicarp is not the skin, as one might expect; it is encased inside the accessory tissue.)
- In [**drupes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupe), such as peaches, the majority of the flesh is the mesocarp. The epicarp forms the skin. The endocarp forms the pit, which surrounds the seed.
- [**Berries**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry) vary depending on whether they are botanical berries or not, and by what type of berries they are. For example, blueberries and grapes (botanical berries) are eaten in their entirety.
- In contrast, [**strawberries**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry) are not botanical berries; they are accessory fruits like apples, so the flesh is accessory tissue. Each "seed" on the strawberry is called an [achene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achene), which is like a miniature fruit including both pericarp and a single seed that fills most of the volume.
- In [**hesperidium**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesperidium) (a modified berry), which are citrus, the epicarp forms the peel, the mesocarp forms the pith, and the endocarp forms the juicy flesh that is eaten.
- From what I can find on [**bananas**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana) (also botanical berries), the epicarp forms the peel, while the mesocarp and endocarp form the flesh that is eaten.

Answer (score -2):

To many people, it's called 'the pit' or 'seed' of the fruit. A center object that you would throw away and not eat. The actual term of the center would be known as the 'Drupe'.

Sources: [Wikipedia, Drupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupe) and
         [Difference between Seeds and Pits](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/difference-between-seeds-and-pits/)

Comment: No, one does not eat the pit.

Comment: First answer? Cool. Could you double-check if the OP is naming the edible part or the pit, per your answer?

Comment: If you had read the Wikipedia article that you linked, you would have seen that "drupe" is the name for a type of fruit containing a pit, not the pit itself.